Rotate instances on a every other column of a grid / cylinder
here is my project: https://we.tl/t-oGBvzlGcwf
This is my goal. I managed to do everything but the mirroring of every 2nd "column".
Now in a grid there are columns but in my case I used a cylinder to get that "rounded" grid so I don't have real columns which I can select with every 2nd index.
How can I only rotate the instances of every 2nd column?

This is what I have so far:

And this is my current node tree:


is that what you wanna achieve? [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/TaM5WdJj.png

@Chris – Holy moly. I love the internet, the community and YOU! :D Thank you so much! I'll try it out. Can't comprehend why there are people out there who are THAT helpful! Feels great, thank you!

you are welcome, if my answer helped you, pls click on the checkmark left of my answer. thx.

@Chris – I already clicked on it because I thought it will for sure help me but sadly this is pretty complex for me so I can't really figure everything out although your documentation is great. Could you please share a screenshot with the full node tree so I can try to better understand what you explained and how it is working? Can't really combine the screenshots, I'm sorry. I will for sure checkmark it!

Man, you humiliated me on a different level, haha! I don't know how i bring the path accumulation and the path with the points to curve together... @Chris And also I don't know whats REALLY happening.

i added the full node tree to my answer

Thank you very much! @Chris That helps a lot!

if you enable attribute text (i am using Blender 4.3 alpha) ...

and use a viewer node, you can see the indices of your points:

As you can see, they are already ordered "right" by y position.
You can easily achieve that, by the points to curve node and using the y-value of your positions as sorting:

what we know want to achieve, is the same value for each column like this:

we can get that, by

compare the next position with the current position y value like this:




accumulate all these "not equal" like this:


now we got a number for each column:


now use a 2nd accumulate node to fill all numbers so you get the "real" column value for each point:



store that info:

Now all you have to do is compare these column values and rotate/mirror as you like:

result:

full node tree:


Did you change anything before adding the viewer node? Because it looks different for me. It's not sorted by those lines. There's a different logic.

of course: i used the "mesh to curves" node as you can see in the third image. There you can see how i connected the viewer node

I would recommend watching Erindale's geometry node videos (he is a master of explaining that) to learn GN and get familiar with it. The other thing to quickly learn is using the viewer node and connect it wherever you don't know what's happening to see the results. Mute all nodes you don't understand, than mute it one by one and watch carefully what's happening - especially with the viewer node and the results in the spreadsheet. Honestly: i am still learning the accumulate node myself and just use it for "easy" cases. Its very powerful!

Thank you! I will check him out! :)

It doesn't work sadly.. Do I have to type "column" in the Named Attribute and Store Name Attribute by hand? I can't see the mistake.. :( https://snipboard.io/sTX5mh.jpg

pls provide your blend file (which doesn't work) then i can check it out. thx.
